# How to catch invalid files when loading large .tsv file into database using LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, load-data-infile

## Task:

Let's say that I have four `tsv` files which are later loaded into separate MySQL tables using JAVA PreparedStatement:

Files format: `Table name - number of columns`

- `Category - 2 columns`
- `Keyword - 2 columns`
- `Url - 3 columns`
- `Relation - 3 columns`

Tables schemas are similar with the addition of 2 columns per table `timestamp` - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `domain` - which is always the same for all four files.

These files are linked to each other, so I chose to use Aurora MySQL because of the relational design which does the mapping for me for free.

## Current approach:

So basically I get an archive file with those 4 files, then I need to load them into DB separately. To improve the performance and improve the logs, I am splitting the files by 60,000 lines each and load them separately using `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL`. This is done only if the file contains more than 100k lines.

#### Example `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL` query - same query for all 4 files just replacing the *table name* and *file path*:

- `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/CATEGORY.www.example.com.tab' INTO TABLE CATEGORY FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\b' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' SET domain = 'www.example.com';`

## Problems:

#### SQL warning - 1261:

Let's assume `Category` file contains only one row and two columns,

Example of a single row in category file: 
*`1    Book` - two columns separated by tab.

The issue here is that I get a warning saying that `Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns` is this because there are two extra columns in the schema which are not in the file? or maybe because I used `set domain=www.example.com`?

### Data validation part.1:

- I would love to make sure that there are no more than 2/3 columns in the file when loaded, is there a way to restrict the number of columns when using `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL` for example if there are more than two columns just fail to load the file at all - but need to give me some warning so I can act on it. *WITHOUT READING THE ENTIRE FILE*

### Data validation part.2

- Let's say the `foreign key constraint` is violated when loading one part of a `Relation` file, is there a way of stopping the file from being imported and to throw me a `warning`/`exception` so I can act on it?

Do you have any suggestions?

Best,
Thank you

PS: I am sorry if I worded some things incorrectly, don't need to be picky here - if you see anything incorrect please let me know and I will fix the question format.

Comment: A good practice is to load the data into staging tables, and then clean and validate the data in the staging tables before moving the data into the base tables.

Comment: That is what I am curently doing, loading them into 4 intermediate tables, create a view with left join including all columns from all 4 files and then I use INSERT INTO SELECT * to copy the date to the base table. However I need to verify the files before I start to do that.

Comment: It's not Java, but here's a Python program to check the format of CSV (or TSV) files that might be useful: https://pypi.org/project/chkcsv/